# jQuery Mobile not resizing page correctly

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile

I'm developing a Phonegap solution using jQuery Mobile and I'm having a problem with page resizing.

[image]

As you can see, the page goes beyond screen size and thus enables scrolling. I've tried resizing on `pageshow`, but no succcess:

```
    $(document).on('pageshow', '[data-role=page]', function () {
        $(window).resize();
    });
```

Even if I remove everything from inside the page, it goes beyond the phones screen - and manually resizing the browser screen doesn't help.

Does anyone know what I can do to fix this issue?

This is the code after JQM has injected some styles and `ui-panel-wrapper`:

```
<div (...) style="position: relative; padding-bottom: 35px; padding-top: 51px; min-height: 393px;">
(...)
</div>
```

**Update**
So it turns out I got this problem because of two (css) things:

```
body {height: 100% }
[data-role="page"] {height: 100%;}
```

I had added this in order to get full screen google maps. Removing these styles fixed my problem. Now I just have to find another way to get full screen maps.

Comment: It might be because of the CSS. I bet on a padding on the `body`. Please provide your CSS and/or a working fiddle.

Comment: Check the style sheets of the body and the jQuery Mobile.

Comment: You are right. JQM adds padding and sets min-height to the page object. But since that's JQM thing, I thought that's how it works and shouldn't give me any problems. See updated question / code

Comment: Ok, so I discovered that if I remove `body {height: 100% }` and set the injected padding to 0, it fixes the issue. The problem is that if I remove the top padding, parts of the page is hidden under my header.

Comment: I also had this: `[data-role="page"] {height: 100%;}` - I added that to get full screen google maps. Removing this solved my problems.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have an image inside the inner div, which causes the div to be bigger than what's left between header and footer, hence also the scrollbar on the right side of the window. Resizing won't help, but you could fix the dimensions of the image to fit between header and footer, or hide the scrollbar by applying the style overflow-y:hidden. As Brewal remarked, more code might help.

Comment: It's a background picture on the `body`, so that's not it. See my updatd code and comment

Comment: For displaying google maps, make sure you display the page before creating the map in it. If necessary, you can restrict the above mentioned CSS rule to a particular class assigned to the page containing the map instead of [data-role="page"]