# Jquery Mobile (JQM) 1.4.5 Page Min-Height Reduces Page Height to less than 100%

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-mobile, resize

I'm trying to correct a bug that's recently been triggered in my multi-page mobile application with a panel dialog. At random, JQuery seems to shorten the min-height of any given page, causing the black footer div to jump up and the side panel to shorten. This happens either when navigating to a new page or when opening the side menu panel.

I've attempted to manipulate the CSS per this threads: [jQuery Mobile not resizing page correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28721276/jquery-mobile-not-resizing-page-correctly)

And then attempted a JavaScript fix here using the window resize event: [jQuery mobile page height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8929786/jquery-mobile-page-height)

But neither have worked so far. It seems the "resize" event never fires, so the callback would never run. I'm not sure what other event I could try that would fire when using JQuery Mobile.

See the jsfiddle for the demonstration: http://jsfiddle.net/m8ws6479/

Code here:

```
<body>
    <div data-role="page" data-position="fixed" id="page1">
        <div data-role="panel" data-display="push" id="menu1" class="menu">
            <div class="menulist">
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#page1">Page 1</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#page2">Page 2</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#page3">Page 3</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#page4">Page 4</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div data-role="header" class="menubar">
            <div class="sidebutton">
                <a href="#menu1">Menu1</a>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
            <div><p>This is page 1</p></div>
        </div>

        <div data-role="footer" style="width:100%; height:200px; background: black; position:absolute; bottom: 0;"></div>
    </div>

    <div data-role="page" data-position="fixed" id="page2">
        <div data-role="panel" data-display="push" id="menu2" class="menu">
            <div class="menulist">
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#page1">Page 1</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#page2">Page 2</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#page3">Page 3</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#page4">Page 4</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div data-role="header" class="menubar">
            <div class="sidebutton">
                <a href="#menu2">Menu2</a>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
            <div><p>This is page 2</p></div>
        </div>

        <div data-role="footer" style="width:100%; height:200px; background: black; position:absolute; bottom: 0;"></div>
    </div>

    <div data-role="page" data-position="fixed" id="page3">
        <div data-role="panel" data-display="push" id="menu3" class="menu">
            <div class="menulist">
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#page1">Page 1</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#page2">Page 2</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#page3">Page 3</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#page4">Page 4</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div data-role="header" class="menubar">
            <div class="sidebutton">
                <a href="#menu3">Menu3</a>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
            <div><p>This is page 3</p></div>
        </div>

        <div data-role="footer" style="width:100%; height:200px; background: black; position:absolute; bottom: 0;"></div>
    </div>

    <div data-role="page" data-position="fixed" id="page4">
        <div data-role="panel" data-display="push" id="menu4" class="menu">
            <div class="menulist">
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#page1">Page 1</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#page2">Page 2</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#page3">Page 3</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#page4">Page 4</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div data-role="header" class="menubar">
            <div class="sidebutton">
                <a href="#menu4">Menu4</a>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
            <div><p>This is page 4</p></div>
        </div>

        <div data-role="footer" style="width:100%; height:200px; background: black; position:absolute; bottom: 0;"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing your footer to this seems to solve the jumping:

```
<div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="false" style="height: 200px; background: black;"></div>
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/m8ws6479/1/)

Comment: That's a start, but the deformation is still there when you look at how the side menu resizes. In the end the footer was more for demonstration purposes; the final version of the webapp doesn't actually use a footer on any given page. I've changed the background color of the .ui-content tag to black and removed the footer: http://jsfiddle.net/m8ws6479/2/